# Retrieve digits after specific string in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a bunch of strings that contain the word "radius" followed by one or two digits. They also contain a lot of other letters, digits, and underscores. For example, one is "inflow100_radius6_distance12". I want a regex that will just return the one or two digits following "radius." If R recognized \K, then I would just use this:

```
radius\K[0-9]{1,2}
```

and be done. But R doesn't allow \K, so I ended up with this instead (which selects radius and the following numbers, and then cuts off "radius"):

```
result <- regmatches(input_string, gregexpr("radius[0-9]{1,2}", input_string))
result <- unlist(substr(result, 7, 8)))
```

I'm pretty new to regex, so I'm sure there's a better way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\K` is recognized. You can solve the problem by turning on the `perl = TRUE` parameter.

```
result <- regmatches(x, gregexpr('radius\\K\\d+', x, perl=T))
```

Answer (score 4):

**1)** Match the entire string replacing it with the digits after `radius`:

```
sub(".*radius(\\d+).*", "\\1", "inflow100_radius6_distance12")
## [1] "6"
```

The regular expression can be visualized as follows:

```
.*radius(\d+).*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Ld2R0lO2S7rjCzeV)

**2)** This also works, involves a simpler regular expression and converts it to numeric at the same time:

```
library(gsubfn)
strapply("inflow100_radius6_distance12", "radius(\\d+)", as.numeric, simplify = TRUE)
## [1] 6
```

Here is a visualization of the regular expression:

```
radius(\d+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/6MNZTYlgpBMfqKcb)